# Change text on a div when it rotates

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

Does anyone have any idea how I can make a text that's inside an

in a div, and change its content when it rotates?

This is what the code is currently doing, I'm able to rotate my text but I have no idea on how to change what's written as soon as the animation finishes.
Also, I'd like to find a way to make this animation endless, so the text is always changing, every time it rotates.

Appreciate the help!!

```css
#text-1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    animation:rotateAnimation 1s alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateY(225deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="div-1">
        <p id="text-1"> Text 1 </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, to make your animation run forever, you are going to want to set the `animation-iteration-count` property, which can be done in shorthand like so:

```
animation: rotateAnimation 1s alternate infinite;
```

Next, because your animation is looping forever, you will want to use the `setInterval()` function in JavaScript to run some code that changes the text on a regular interval. This will also allow you to stop the text changing using the `clearInterval()` function.

Because your animation is set to alternate and has a time of 1 second for the animation, it actually takes 2 seconds to complete your animation (I'm not sure if that is your goal but it is what you provided).

I'm also using `setTimeout()` to add a delay before the text is initially changed. Again, a lot of this is probably going to come down to how **you** want to tweak the animation.

```js
let interval;
setTimeout(() => {
  _ChangeText();
  interval = setInterval(_ChangeText, 2000);
}, 200);

const _ChangeText = () => {
  document.querySelector("#text-1").innerText = (document.querySelector("#text-1").innerText == "Text 1") ? "Text 2" : "Text 1";
}
```

```css
#text-1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotateAnimation 1s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <p id="text-1"> Text 1 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript:

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.querySelector("#text-1").innerHTML = "Wooo";
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 800)
```

```css
#text-1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    animation:rotateAnimation 1s alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateY(225deg);
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="div-1">
        <p id="text-1"> Text 1 </p>
    </div>
```

You might need to change timing in order to you website.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked just fine, exactly what i was looking for!
Is there any way i can make this keep running forever, and changing the text everytime it rotates??

Comment: It stops after the animation is over, because you added alternate-reverse. If you want to loop it, you need to write infinite.

Comment: EssXTee has written a bitte code for you :)

Comment: @PauloPaiva My answer addresses your question from this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using another `keyframe` with a pseudo-element.

```css
#text-1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotateAnimation 1s alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
}

#text-1:after {
  content: "";
  animation: changeText 1.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeText {
  0% {
    content: "Text 1";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Text 2";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <p id="text-1"></p>
</div>
```

Here is a version with a longer duration. To make it longer just add more intervals.

```css
#text-1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotateAnimation 10s alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

#text-1:after {
  content: "";
  animation: changeText 10s alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeText {
  0% {
    content: "Text 1";
  }
  10% {
    content: "Text 2";
  }
  20% {
    content: "Text 3";
  }
  30% {
    content: "Text 4";
  }
  40% {
    content: "Text 5";
  }
  50% {
    content: "Text 6";
  }
  60% {
    content: "Text 7";
  }
  70% {
    content: "Text 8";
  }
  80% {
    content: "Text 9";
  }
  90% {
    content: "Text 10";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Text 11";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <p id="text-1"></p>
</div>
```